# Use firefox for Selenium in CircleCI 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, circleci, circleci-2.0

In my CircleCI config.yml file I have the following:

```
docker:
  - image: circleci/ruby:2.5.3-browsers-legacy
```

In the [CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/) it says that by attaching -browsers-legacy to the language it will include Chrome, Firefox, Java 8 and PhantomJS

And I also tried adding to the config.yml:

```
- image: selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59
```

But I am still getting the error:

```
Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
       (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

What config should I use instead?

Comment: Can you share your full .yml configuration file data?

Comment: How are you specifying geckodriver path in your program. This `Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver` error is saying that the geckodriver is not found not the browser. There is a difference between `geckodriver` and `browser`.

Comment: @AliCSE locally I added the geckodriver to my path, but I do not know how to do that on CircleCI

Comment: Ok, don't place `geckodriver` outside of your project and include it inside of your project only and provide that path using `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir"+//geckodriverpath))`. And make sure that, you are passing `Linux` or `MacOS` executable drivers because `Circle CI` has only Mac and Linux os support not windows. OR why don't you simply use `WebDriverManager` to avoid worrying about drivers. Check out my code https://bitbucket.org/alicse3/automation-with-selenium, I have recently executed in Circle CI by using Chrome.

Comment: @AliCSE I switched to Chrome but now I am getting an error with one of the tests that clear cookies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253722/redirect-to-sign-in-page-if-ajax-call-is-not-authorized

Comment: Using the webdrivers gem should auto-install geckodriver for you.