# Redirect_to sign in page if AJAX call is not authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I have a form and when you click `submit` it will make an AJAX call to update the thing you want to change. My user session expires in 4 hours, so if the user wants to update the form and his session has expired in the meantime it will render a flash message asking to reload the page and sign in again.

When trying to test this behavior using `Cucumber`, `Capybara`, `Selenium` and `Chrome` the AJAX response is never received as the flash message is not rendered. (If I test it manually it works just fine)

I have run another test that renders the flash message when performing another action that also uses AJAX and it succeeds. The difference is that one action renders a view right away and the one that fails redirects to another path and then renders. All controllers inherit from the same BaseController that checks if the user is authorized.

After expiring the session, I call submit form which has these steps:

```
When /^I submit the form$/ do
  generic_form_page = GenericFormPage.new(Capybara.current_session)
  generic_form_page.submit

  if Capybara.current_session.mode == :poltergeist
    ajax_page = GenericAjaxPage.new Capybara.current_session
    ajax_page.wait_for_ajax_call_to_finish
  else
    Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 50)
  end
  sleep 5
end
```

`wait_for_ajax_call_to_finish` basically just sleeps for a couple of seconds

This is the action that is failing:

```
  def update
    @element = Element.find(params[:id])
    if @element.update_attributes(element_params)
      render :json => { :location => another_path(@element.item) }
    else
      render :action => 'edit', :layout => false
    end
  end
```

The action that is succeeding:

```
  def edit
    @element = Element.find(params[:id])
    @item = @element.item
    render :layout => false
  end
```

The AJAX message is this:

```
handle_ajax_errors = (event, request, settings) ->
  if request.status == 401
    render_flash_error_message("Your session has timed out. Please refresh the page.")
  else
    render_flash_error_message("We're sorry. An error has occurred.")
```

This is how I am expiring the cookies:

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  if browser.respond_to?(:clear_cookies)
    # Rack::MockSession
    browser.clear_cookies
  elsif browser.respond_to?(:manage) and browser.manage.respond_to?(:delete_all_cookies)
    # Selenium::WebDriver
    browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
  else
    raise "Don't know how to clear cookies. Weird driver?"
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your test.log show regarding the requests that are being made?  Where/how are you expiring the session in your test? Also - `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 50)` does nothing other than create an ojbect of class wait and then discard it

Comment: @ThomasWalpole test.log doesn't say anything relevant, as no errors show up with the action I am testing. `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 50)` might not do anything, but I tried with `sleep 40` and also failed

Comment: @ThomasWalpole it works when using Firefox browser, but not Chrome. (But I am having trouble making firefox work on CircleCI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213428/use-firefox-for-selenium-in-circleci-2-0

Comment: but does the test.log show the redirect response? Does it show the Ajax request being received? Does it show the expected requests/responses?